# Loaded data is not available in server function

Tags: r, shiny

I need help I have seen similar questions answered but I just can't get it right and it's driving me nuts.

So here is the problem, when I run the app with ctr + a all works wonderfully, but when I click the Run App button I got the following error

`Error in hasGroups(choices) : object 'my_data' not found`

also if I just run the script in a single file (not really viable the original its too big) it works
Here is the script
**Code**

```
library("tidyverse")
library("readxl")
library("writexl")
library("shiny")

write_xlsx(x = iris, path = "app/IRIS.xlsx")
my_data2 <- read_excel(path = "app/IRIS.xlsx")

source("app/pre_process.R")
my_data <- rename(my_data2)

# comment source and uncomment ui and server and it will work fine
source("app/ui.R")
source("app/server.R")

# ui <- pageWithSidebar(
#   headerPanel('my_data k-means clustering'),
#   sidebarPanel(
#     selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(my_data)),
#     selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(my_data),
#                 selected=names(my_data)[[2]]),
#     numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
#                  min = 1, max = 9)
#   ),
#   mainPanel(
#     plotOutput('plot1')
#   )
# )

# server <- function(input, output, session) {
#   
#   # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
#   selectedData <- reactive({
#     my_data %>% select(input$xcol, input$ycol)
#   })
#   
#   clusters <- reactive({
#     kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
#   })
#   
#   output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
#     palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
#               "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))
#     
#     par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
#     plot(selectedData(),
#          col = clusters()$cluster,
#          pch = 20, cex = 3)
#     points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
#   })
#   
# }
servidor <- server
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**pre_process**

```
rename <- function(my_data) {
  names(my_data) <- c("tallo_l", "tallo_w", "petalo_l", "petalo_w", "especie")
  return(my_data)
}
```

and here is the

**Github Repository**

https://github.com/alfonsonoguer/pre-process-app

In general I just dont know where I have to write the code for it to get loaded to the shiny environment.

And thank you for your time and attention it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of where (i.e. in which environment) R looks for the ui and server file:

If you add the argument `local=TRUE` when sourcing `ui.R` and `server.R` then the app should run both when run using the Run App button and interactively from the script. This is the equivalent of printing the contents of the two files directly into your script.

See also the explanations [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html), in particular the section "Scope for included R files".